# I need a Twitter widget that isn't hideous

Tags: twitter

I need a Twitter widget that isn't chunky and disgusting like the official one (http://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets/widget_profile) and more like this one on some guy's blog (http://kelwynshade.blogspot.com/).

I've checked his source, obviously - and it appears to be part of the Google Friend Connect service, which seems like it aims to solve a lot of problems I just don't have.  And by that I mean it's bloated as hell.

Please advise.

Comment: Are you using wordpress or just looking for a simple widget?

Comment: A simple widget would be ideal.  I'm integrating WordPress onto the same page, though, so if you've got a WP widget I could maybe make it play together.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, ultimately I determined that I had enough CSS control over the stock widget to make do.  If anyone has a better solution though I'd still like to hear it.

Answer (score -1):

I dont know if this helps but u can check the post to twitter app from here:

http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/67.html

and  here

http://marakana.com/techtv/android_bootcamp_screencast_series.html

Hope it helpes:)

Comment: ...This appears to be an Android development article.  Swing and a miss.